# angular cli webpack beta.24 global bootstrap and jquery not working

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm learning the angular2 using angular-cli beta24.  I want to set the bootstrap and jquery globally.  I followed the instructions on the [angular-cli page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation),but it did not work.  I want to know how to solve this problem.

NodeJS version: 6.9.2

OS: Windows 10 64bit

bootstrap version: 3.3.7

jquery version: 3.1.1

angular-cli.json:
[image]

the error shown in browser:
[image]

Comment: Did you restart the Angular2 application after adding the scripts to angular-cli.json? I mean run `ng serve` again.

Comment: sure, I restarted it, but it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a new terminal and install bootstrap and jquery using following npm commands

```
npm install bootstrap --save-dev
npm install jquery --save-dev
```

After that open up your angular.json file and add following lines

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "styles.css"
],
```

And

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
],
```

Answer (score -1):

You appear to be missing JQuery. Load JQuery prior to Bootstrap and it should resolve your issue.

[JQuery Website](https://jquery.com/)

[How JQuery Works Example](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

Excerpt:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>

    // Your code goes here.

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With angular-cli you don't have to add jquery in the index.html, you can add it to the angular-cli.json config file.